# Can VS Code type text with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know you can enter a block of text with code snippets but can you configure keyboard shortcuts to enter some text?
With "editor.action" you can move the cursor but I can't find if it's possible if you can get it to type some text.

Something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> would be "); then a new line

Maybe create a code snippet and then invoke it with a keyboard shortcut?

Is there a way to find what all the options are for "editor.action" ?

Answer (score 44):

You can insert a [User Snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) on keypress:

> Open keybindings.json (Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)), which defines all your keybindings, and add a keybinding passing "snippet" as an extra argument

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "\");\n$0"
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you can specify [languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) in which it should work:

```json
"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'javascript'"
```

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets) for more information.

Comment: I had success with `Cmd+Shift+P > Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the simple command `type` in a keybinding like:

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "type",
    "args": { 
      "text": "myText" 
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of available keyboard actions is available from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings). You can consider to write an [extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) for VS Code if you have something specific in mind, with that you can create actions with keybindings that modify the editor contents.

Comment: Actually that link lists pretty much everything *except* the available keyboard actions.  It does list all of the actions that are bound be default, but AFAIK, this is no complete listing of all available actions, and certainly not the available arguments either.

Answer (score 1):

I just leave it here. An alias for triple backticks for people with non-English keyboards:

````json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+1",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId == 'markdown'",
        "args":{
            "snippet": "```"
        }
    }
````