# What Visual Studio Code command can I use to type text into an **already open and focused** command palette / Quick Open?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

The title is really the full question so here's some more context.

I'm trying to create a macro in Visual Studio Code that executes a sequence of actions. I'm picking between [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.macros) and [Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.commands) to do this, but regardless I have the problem where the actions I'm trying to execute only bring up the command palette / Quick Open and the user still needs to choose an option, and I can't find a built-in command to send text to the ***already open and focused*** command palette / Quick Open.

For example, I want to run [Transformer's](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dakara.transformer) "Decode Base64" action. That extension exposes the command `dakara-transformer.escapes` which brings up the command palette / Quick Open with a list of encode and decode actions, but the user needs to pick the specific entry from the list. Unfortunately, that command takes no arguments that I can use to make this selection.

[image: Animation showing the Transform: Encode/Decode command that prompts the user to choose an option]

In that specific case I can work around the problem by using `workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext` and `workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem` to manually go down the list and select the item I want, but there are some other similar actions I want to execute where this becomes a hassle. Also, I would like the macro to not break if the order of the list changes.

I've found several similar questions, such as [Can I pass a custom text argument to the command palette in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76237437/can-i-pass-a-custom-text-argument-to-the-command-palette-in-vscode), [Can VS Code type text with keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254732/can-vs-code-type-text-with-keyboard-shortcuts) and [How to enter text in command palette in VSCode extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800066/how-to-enter-text-in-command-palette-in-vscode-extension). (That last question I think is the same as mine, but the OP marked as accepted an answer that doesn't really address their original question.)

Based on the answers to those questions, I've tried

```
"sequence": [
    {
        "command": "dakara-transformer.escapes",
    },
    {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
            "text": "Decode Base64"
        }
    }
]
```

... which opens the command palette / Quick Open in the context of Transformer with the text box focused but nothing is typed in the text box, and

```
"sequence": [
    {
        "command": "dakara-transformer.escapes",
    },
    {
        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "args": "Decode Base64"
    }
]
```

... which dismisses the command palette / Quick Open opened by Transformer, opens a new one not in the context of Transformer, and then types "Decode Base64" into the new command palette / Quick Open. The attempt below has the same problem:

```
"sequence": [
    {
        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "args": ">Transform: Encode / Decode"
    },
    {
        "command": "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem"
    },
    {
        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "args": "Decode Base64"
    }
]
```

Comment: add a feature request at the extension that it should accept an `args` with all the settings the user would otherwise select from QuickPick and QuickInput UI